# Pycharm unresolved attribute reference warning

Tags: pycharm, python-3.4, augmented-assignment

Please consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

r = [1, 0, -1, 0]
bins = np.fft.fft(r) / len(r)
x = bins.view(float)
```

Given the above code PyCharm returns this warning: `Unresolved attribute reference 'view' for class 'int'`
If I split line 4 into two lines like

```
bins = np.fft.fft(r)
bins = bins / len(r)
```

, the same warning appears. Only the following does not throw a warning:

```
bins = np.fft.fft(r)
bins /= len(r)
```

Why does PyCharm treat `bins` as of type `int` in the first two versions and how and why does augmented assignment change this behavior?

I am running PyCharm 4.5.1 Community Edition on Yosemite.

Comment: I see the same behavior on PyCharm 4.5.1 Professional Edition on Mavericks (OS X 10.9.5), with Python 3.4.1 (Anaconda 2.1.0)

Comment: There are no 'view' in a second and third piece of code. How the second piece of code can generate such warning? I've checked in PyCharm 2017.1.1 for Linux and I'm right.